# Trying to read firebase database but a syntax error occurred

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I was reading through Firebase web documentation on reading and writing data from a database, I want to add dynamic counters on my github website so i figured Firebase would be the way to go, I attempted to use code found on the documentation as an example, but the example simply outputs an error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Illegal return statement", below is my testing code i ran, the error occurred at line 22(the return statement)

```html
<body>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.15.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script>
  // Your web app's Firebase configuration
  var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyDsjjwO1Jj0VKeZECp6l2NRgOKy9Yb0fYc",
    authDomain: "site-counter-555dd.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://site-counter-555dd.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "site-counter-555dd",
    storageBucket: "site-counter-555dd.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "796019929207",
    appId: "1:796019929207:web:51db340ecf1a53891e1672",
    measurementId: "G-33WHDZ8X6K"
  };
  // Initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
</script>
<script>
var userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
return firebase.database().ref('/Downloads' + userId).once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
  var username = (snapshot.val() && snapshot.val().username) || 'Anonymous'
});
</script></body>
```

Comment: As the error message says, the `return` you have in `return firebase.database()...` is invalid. As this is a top-level script, there is nothing to return from. If you just remove the `return` keyword, this error will disappear.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use a `return` statement that's not within a function.  Start by removing the return - there is nothing to return from.